# 64bit .lib linking not working, 32bit version works fine

Tags: c++, static-libraries

I am using OpenNN2.0, and it compiles fine, both 64bit as well as 32bit.

When I compile my application with 32bit, everything works fine, when I set the solution to be 64bit, I get linker errors.

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl OpenNN::DataSet::set(unsigned __int64 const &,unsigned __int64 const &,unsigned __int64 const &)" (?set@DataSet@OpenNN@@QEAAXAEB_K00@Z)
```

The code causing this error:

```
OpenNN::DataSet data_set;    
const unsigned __int64 i = 1;    
data_set.set( i, i, i);
```

If I do

```
data_set.set( );
```

instead, it compiles just fine. I checked the output from `dumpbin /ALL OpenNN2.0.lib` and it contains

```
  54A6D10 ?set@DataSet@OpenNN@@QEAAXAEBVXMLDocument@tinyxml2@@@Z
  54A6D10 ?set@DataSet@OpenNN@@QEAAXAEB_K00@Z
  54A6D10 ?set@DataSet@OpenNN@@QEAAXAEB_K0@Z
```

so I think it should work, but it doesn't. What is going on here, and how can I rectify it? It is as if the conversion 64bit integer isn't working or something along those lines, I cannot really figure it out.

From the OpenNN Header (data_set.h):

```
   // Set methods

   void set(void);
   void set(const Matrix<double>&);
   void set(const size_t&, const size_t&);
   void set(const size_t&, const size_t&, const size_t&);
   void set(const DataSet&);
   void set(const tinyxml2::XMLDocument&);
   void set(const std::string&);
```

Implementation in the .cpp:

```
void DataSet::set(void)
{

   data_file_name = "";

   data.set();

   variables.set();
   instances.set();

   display = true;
}


// void set(const Matrix<double>&) method

/// Sets all variables from a data matrix.
/// @param new_data Data matrix.

void DataSet::set(const Matrix<double>& new_data)
{
   data_file_name = "";

   const size_t variables_number = new_data.get_columns_number();
   const size_t instances_number = new_data.get_rows_number();

   data = new_data;

   variables.set(variables_number);
   instances.set(instances_number);

   display = true;
}


// void set(const size_t&, const size_t&) method

/// Sets new numbers of instances and variables in the inputs targets data set. 
/// All the instances are set for training. 
/// All the variables are set as inputs. 
/// @param new_variables_number Number of variables.
/// @param new_instances_number Number of instances.

void DataSet::set(const size_t& new_variables_number, const size_t& new_instances_number)
{
    // Control sentence (if debug)

    #ifndef NDEBUG

    if(new_variables_number == 0)
    {
       std::ostringstream buffer;

       buffer << "OpenNN Exception: DataSet class.\n"
              << "void set(const size_t&, const size_t&) method.\n"
              << "Number of variables must be greater than zero.\n";

       throw std::logic_error(buffer.str());
    }

    if(new_instances_number == 0)
    {
       std::ostringstream buffer;

       buffer << "OpenNN Exception: DataSet class.\n"
              << "void set(const size_t&, const size_t&) method.\n"
              << "Number of instances must be greater than zero.\n";

       throw std::logic_error(buffer.str());
    }

    #endif

   data.set(new_instances_number, new_variables_number);

   instances.set(new_instances_number);

   variables.set(new_variables_number);
}


// void set(const size_t&, const size_t&, const size_t&) method

/// Sets new numbers of instances and inputs and target variables in the data set.
/// The variables in the data set are the number of inputs plus the number of targets. 
///
/// @param new_inputs_number Number of input variables.
/// @param new_targets_number Number of target variables.
/// @param new_instances_number Number of instances.

void DataSet::set(const size_t& new_inputs_number, const size_t& new_targets_number, const size_t& new_instances_number)
{   
   data_file_name = "";

   const size_t new_variables_number = new_inputs_number + new_targets_number;

   data.set(new_instances_number, new_variables_number);

   // Variables

   variables.set(new_inputs_number, new_targets_number);

   // Instances

   instances.set(new_instances_number);

   display = true;
}
```

Comment: When I look at a [github copy](https://github.com/orian/opennn/blob/master/source/data_set.h) of this library, I see set() functions that take `unsigned`, not `size_t`.  How did this happen?   Have you been editing the source of this library?

Comment: No, I took the source from https://sourceforge.net/projects/opennn since that is what the author from OpenNN told me to. I did not alter any source codes.

Comment: Works just fine when I try it.  Where did OpenNN2.0.lib come from?  The SourceForge distribution does not contain any binaries.  Rebuilding from source, like I did, is surely your best avenue.  Create a VS static library project, add all the .cpp files to it.

Comment: I used CMAKE to create the solution and compiled from ground up. I just tested with the github code, and it contains several compilation errors. I will try with a completely new solution, I have to admit I did not test that.

Comment: Okay, this is working now. I am wondering what caused it to fail in the first place. If you want, you can post this as the answer that creating the 32bit solution from CMAKE and expanding to 64bit might have caused this (for whatever reason).